# xgboost plot_tree(model) - Fix TypeError: super(type, obj) when Running

Tags: python-3.x, xgboost

When I ran the code:

```
plot_tree(model)
```

I get the error as below.

How could I fix it?

I suspect it could be an issue of installing the graphviz package, for which I did the following:

- Install windows package from
  (https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/Download/Download_windows.html)Install python graphviz package (using anaconda prompt “pip install graphviz)
- Install python graphviz package (using anaconda prompt “pip install
  graphviz)
- Add C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin to User path
- Add C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin\dot.exe to System Path

Error:

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Traceback (most recent call last):
File “”, line 1, in
plot_tree(model)
File “C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xgboost\plotting.py”, line 278, in plot_tree
rankdir=rankdir, **kwargs)
File “C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xgboost\plotting.py”, line 227, in to_graphviz
graph = Digraph(graph_attr=kwargs)
File “C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\graphviz\dot.py”, line 61, in __init__
super(Dot, self).__init__(filename, directory, format, engine, encoding)
TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```